# About package naming in java

Tags: java, package

For example, I have a .java file at:

/home/me/sandbox/A/B/C.java

In the first line of this file, which one of the following should I write after `package`? And why?

`sandbox.A.B` or `A.B` or `B`?

Comment: well that depends where you're importing it from...

Comment: And it depends on what you WANT the package name to be...

Comment: It could be `me.sandbox.A.B` or nothing if `/home/me/sandbox/A/B` is your root.

Comment: source path isn't so relevant. You can have in the very same folder src/foo  two java files containing different packages (net.sample.foo and net.sample.bar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working with an `IDE` like `Eclipse`, you can do the following :

1) Create a new Java project.

2) Copy your "me" folder to the project.

3) Right click on "me" folder -> Build Path -> Add as source folder.

4) Now you will observe that sandbox.A.B will appear as a package with class C.java in it (provided you write `package sandbox.A.B` at the top of the C.java file).

Answer (score 3):

What's your source folder, what's still part of your program? I'd guess you have to write `A.B` (if sandbox is the root source folder and not part of the namespace).

Answer (score 1):

You should mention the source folder from which the relative namespace must start. In your case you may write package A.B if you have A as source folder.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the current working directory where you will store your java file.